# How to sort by more than one property of an object - linq4j

Tags: java, linq4j

I am using linq4j. I am only sorting by one property and would like to sort by multiple property. If is is not supported in linq4j than what other method I can use. Following is my code snippet,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List; 
import net.hydromatic.linq4j.Linq4j;
import net.hydromatic.linq4j.function.*;

public class Linq4jExample {
 public static class Employee {
 public final int empno;
 public final String name;
 public final int deptno;

public Employee(int empno, String name, int deptno) {
  this.empno = empno;
  this.name = name;
  this.deptno = deptno;
}

public String toString() {
  return "Employee(empno: " + empno +",name: " + name + ", deptno:" + deptno    + ")";
 }
 }

public static final Employee[] emps = {
  new Employee(100, "Fred", 10),
  new Employee(110, "Bill", 30),
  new Employee(120,  "Bill", 10),
  new Employee(120, "Eric", 12),
  new Employee(130, "Janet", 13),
};

public static final Function1<Employee, Integer> EMP_DEPTNO_SELECTOR =
  new Function1<Employee, Integer>() {
    public Integer apply(Employee employee) {
      return employee.deptno;
    }
     };

public static void main(String[] args) {

  List<Employee> filter=Linq4j.asEnumerable(Arrays.asList(emps)) 
            .orderBy(new Function1<Employee,String>()
        { 
        public String apply(Employee arg0)
        {
            return arg0.name;
        }

    }).toList();

  }
 }
```

A potential use case could be sorting by department number and then by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple order by in linq4j. Check the following example

```
package maven_lab;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.calcite.linq4j.Linq4j;
import org.apache.calcite.linq4j.function.Function1;

public class Linq4jExample {

    public static final Employee[] emps = {
            new Employee(100, "Fred", 10),
            new Employee(110, "Bill", 30),
            new Employee(120, "Bill", 10),
            new Employee(120, "henry", 10),
            new Employee(120, "Adam", 10),
            new Employee(120, "Eric", 12),
            new Employee(130, "Janet", 13),
    };

    public static final Function1<Employee, Integer> EMP_DEPTNO_SELECTOR =
            new Function1<Employee, Integer>() {
                public Integer apply(Employee employee) {
                    return employee.deptno;
                }
            };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> filter = Linq4j.asEnumerable(Arrays.asList(emps)).orderBy(e -> e.deptno)
            .orderBy(e -> e.name).toList();

        System.out.println(filter);

    }

    public static class Employee {
        public final int empno;
        public final String name;
        public final int deptno;

        public Employee(int empno, String name, int deptno) {
            this.empno = empno;
            this.name = name;
            this.deptno = deptno;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Employee(empno: " + empno + ",name: " + name + ", deptno:" + deptno + ")";
        }
    }


}
```

Notice that I am ordering by department first and then the name. You should also use jdk8 lambda instead of anonymous classes.

---

Pre JDK8 you can do this like following,

```
 List<Employee> filter = Linq4j.asEnumerable(Arrays.asList(emps)).orderBy(new Function1<Employee, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(Employee arg0) {
                return arg0.deptno;
            }

        }).orderBy(new Function1<Employee, String>() {
            public String apply(Employee arg0) {
                return arg0.name;
            }

        }).toList();
```

Comment: My project use jdk7.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: It is not the then by function what I want.It is equal to order by name.I have try your answer.